# Comparing two States of the Same Database Schema using maven liquibase

Tags: maven, liquibase

During the development of our product, and as many developers are putting changes into the database, there is a need to get a list of all the DB changes done in comparison to the previous version of our our product.

I am using liquibase on a maven project, e.g:

```
mvn clean liquibase:update
```

Is there a way to achieve what I need?

Thanks

Comment: When you say previous version, is that pervious version accessible via a JDBC Connection?

Answer (score 0):

> there is a need to get a list of all the DB changes done in comparison
> to the previous version of our our product.

This task seems like a manual task, and not a part of your automation pipeline.  I am making that assumption b/c you will want to analyze the diff results right?  So, if we take out the mvn layer, you can run [liquibase diff](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/diff.html).

Of course you can add it to your pom, and you will need to add additional values that would normally go into your liquibase.properties file.  maven will need to know source and target db urls.  Then just run

`mvn clean liquibase:diff`

Comment: Thanks, but the question is if mvn liquibase diff supports a comparison to a prvious version of the same database.

Comment: diff just supports comparing 2 different databases.  Maybe if you have database 1 at a version and database 2 restored with a previous version that would qualify as comparing 2 different versions but, its not like you can point to one db and use diff to compare it to a early version level of the db (how would you specify it?  by date?).